# JavaScript encode field without spoiling the display

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, get, encodeuricomponent

I want to encode a specific search field before submitting as a $_GET request. What I am doing is to apply encodeURIComponent() function over that field before the form is submitted

```
$('#frmMainSearch').submit(function() {
    var field = $(this).find('#searchinput');
    field.val(encodeURIComponent(field.val()));
});
```

the issue is that as soon as the text is encoded, the field displays the encoded text which looks a bit weird. Is there anything I can do to avoid it?

Example:
I type **Hello & Hello**. When I click submit button it turns into something like **Hello %26 Hello** before the page is refreshed. I want to avoid that.

Any solution?

Thanks

Comment: *"I want to encode a specific search field before submitting as a $_GET request."* Why? Sending the form **will** encode the field. What you're doing will *double*-encode it.

Comment: T.J. Crowder is probably right, but if you would want to anyway you can have a hidden field with the name that the searchinput has, and let the searchfield not have any name. And give the hidden field the encoded value.

Comment: @Crowder actually that does not perform the proper search from the DB if I let my browser encode it. That's why I am manually encoding it. To Hatlen, this seems like a good idea but I wanted to get the data through the $_GET variable and with the same field name. If I create a hidden field, then the users will have to post the form again, then they won't be able to refresh from the browser URL. Hope you're getting me.

Comment: @user2335977 what your describing will break the web. There has to be something else in your code that is encoding it.

Comment: So should I manually encode it or not? If the browser encodes it then I will have to look into my SQL query to make it work because it does not work with the browser encoding but my manual encoding. Thanks all for your feedback :-) Appreciated.

Comment: @user2335977: Please rather fix your server to properly decode it instead of trying to produce the only accepted format manually.

Comment: Right. I tried urldecode() but that also did not help. Righr now I'm outside. Will try something else when I get back. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently had to solve this same problem. Here's how I did it:

1. Create the input field that you want to be user-facing, such as this:

   ```
   <input class="really-nice-looking-field" 
          id="search-text-display" 
          placeholder="Search for stuff..." 
          type="text">
   ```
2. Notice that with the field that's displayed, the `name` attribute is specifically omitted. This will keep the `search-text-display` field out of the submitted form, so you don't have unused parameters coming through.
3. Create a hidden field, which is what will *actually* be used for the submit, like so:

   ```
   <input id="search-text" name="search_text" type="hidden">
   ```
4. Capture the submit event from your form to populate the hidden field before the form is submitted, like so:

   ```
   $('#site-search').submit(function() {
       $('#search-text').val(
           encodeURIComponent($('#search-text-display').val())
       );
   });
   ```

This will leave the input field displayed to your users untouched while your parameters come through escaped, as needed:

```
    Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search_text"=>"hello%20%26%20hello"}
```