# Encoded value is displaying on textbox :- encodeURIComponent()

Tags: javascript, asp.net, encodeuricomponent

I'm calling a `javascript` function on `OnClientClick` of my button control to encode a textbox value .
That JS function calls `encodeURIComponent()` to encode the text value of textbox.

My Javascript function is

```js
function Validate() {
    var d = document.getElementById('<%=NoteText.ClientID %>');
    var Hdn = document.getElementById('HdnProcessing');
    if (d.value == '') {
        alert(document.getElementById('<%=NotesMessage.ClientID %>').value);
        d.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (Hdn.value == "Processing") {
        return false;
    } else {
        Hdn.value = "Processing";
        var headObj = document.getElementById('<%=NoteHeading.ClientID %>');
        headObj.value = encodeURIComponent(headObj.value);
        d.value = encodeURIComponent(d.value);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here my inputs are textboxes ie NoteText and NoteHeading.

If anyone is reading this I was wondering is there anyway to pass the encoded text to the server without the user seeing the encoded text updating in the textbox. Currently when the user clicks the SAVE button they see the text change to the encoded text for a split second before the page refreshes. I was just curious if I could prevent the user from seeing that.

Comment: What is the desired behavior? Which textbox should have the encoded text? Which inputs are textboxes (i.e., NoteText, NotesMessage, NoteHeading, all of the above, etc.)?

Comment: you use `encodeURIComponent` but here no `decodeURIComponent` should it be so?

Comment: Notetext and Noteheading is the inputs,we need the encoded value of this textboxes to save values .We are not using decodeURIComponent.We used this encodeURIComponent because some times we will add angle brackets values also into the textboxes ie<text>.

Answer (score 0):

I recently provided an answer to a very similar question that should help you out:

[JavaScript encode field without spoiling the display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288968/javascript-encode-field-without-spoiling-the-display)